# Angular app based on keycloak keep loading infinitly when refreshing the page or after login

Tags: angular, keycloak

I try to conserve the current state of my angular app (the url) each time I refresh the page to stay on the same component by proceeding like that:
changing the value of the redirectUri in the isAccessAllowed:

```
public async isAccessAllowed(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot
    ) {
        // Force the user to log in if currently unauthenticated.
        if (!this.authenticated) {
            await this.keycloak.login({
                redirectUri: window.location.origin
            });
        }

        // Get the roles required from the route.
        const requiredRoles = route.data['roles'];

        // Allow the user to proceed if no additional roles are required to access the route.
        if (!Array.isArray(requiredRoles) || requiredRoles.length === 0) {
            return true;
        }

        // Allow the user to proceed if all the required roles are present.
        return requiredRoles.every((role) => this.roles.includes(role));
    }
```

from what is mentionned above to the following:

```
redirectUri: window.location.origin + state.url
```

but that caused an infinite loading each time I refresh the page, and in case I don't add this state.url parameter I lose the last page I was located in each time I reload the page.
One thing I noticed is that while this infinite loading is runing, the url in the browser change for example suppose the current url is: localhost:4200/students, when refreshing the page it beacome: http://localhost:4200/students/#state=97adb035-6f54-48f4-80ce-5bdab263d473&session_state=59258d8a-266c-43b5-a5ee-e983cd06a1b9&code=55c1ad08-3981-4b8a-8ad3-558c9fc3cc76.59258d8a-266c-43b5-a5ee-e983cd06a1b9.0745ea0b-b772-48d9-ac65-2cab34cf9b50&state...
and then switch back to http://localhost:4200/students, and continue like that infinitely.
here's my keycloak configuration in the app.module:

```
export function kcFactory(kcService: KeycloakService) {
    return () => {
        kcService.init({
            config: {
                realm: "students",
                clientId: "studentsClient",
                url: "http://localhost:8080"
            },
            loadUserProfileAtStartUp: true,
            initOptions: {
                // onLoad: "check-sso",
                onLoad: "login-required",
                checkLoginIframe: true,
            },
        })
    }
}
```

keycloak version: 21.1.1,
keycloak-angular: 14.1.0,
keycloak-js: 22.0.1,
Can someone help me please.

Answer (score 1):

I think to avoid the infinite loop and the redirect to `http://localhost:4200/`, your app.routing should look like this:

```
NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    initialNavigation: 'enabledBlocking',
    useHash: false,
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
  ,providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }]
})
```

Comment: Hi kerry love, thank you for your response, can you please explain me what does that code do?

Comment: Any way I tried, but it didn't work.

Comment: infact, providers: [{ provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }]adds  # in the urls and useHash: false, allows to remove the state and stop the infinite loop.I did it with react js but i don't know if it could work with angular

Comment: @kerrylove When you answer the question with code sample, please make sure you explain what it does. You can also try if your solution works or not before posting.